# Android AlarmManager setRepeating doesn't repeat with long interval

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've implemented AlarmManager to wake the phone once a day to perform an update task, update widgets and send notifications if applicable.

I'm using `setRepeating` and `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` 
The alarm is triggered the first time (`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000`)
but it doesn't get triggered `86400000` milliseconds (24 hours) later.

Really struggling with this, I'm happy to accept im doing something wrong or if there are better ways to achieve what I'm trying to do. However I think my code looks like the standard thing people seem to do.

It's almost like the repeating alarm doesn't do what it says it should in all cases. If I reduce the interval to say 10 minutes it does work, my alarm triggers and the service is run over and over.

The nature of my app means updating more than once a day is overkill.
I need to find a realistic reliable solution to this.

Thanks for your time & hope you can point me in the right direction.

Here's my alarm implementation code...

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".SystemChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name=".UpdateAlarmReceiver" />
<service android:name=".UpdateService" />
<receiver android:name=".WidgetProviderSmall" android:label="@string/widget_small_label">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/appwidget_small" />
</receiver>
<receiver android:name=".WidgetProviderLarge" android:label="@string/widget_large_label">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/appwidget_large" />
</receiver>
```

`SystemChangeReceiver` listens for the boot broadcast, checks if an alarm needs to be set, if it does, it sets it.

`SystemChangeReceiver`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.prefs_name), 0);

    Boolean notifications = prefs.getBoolean("enable_updates", false);
    if(notifications == true) {
        Utils.setNotificationAlarm(context);
    }
}
```

The setNotificationAlarm method, sets up the repeating alarm...

```
public static void setNotificationAlarm(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000,
            86400000,
            pi);
}
```

When the alarm triggers my receiver `UpdateAlarmReceiver` decides what to do and using `WakefulIntentService` runs my background update process, the handler for the service then updates widgets and sends notifications as required

`UpdateAlarmReceiver`:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, UpdateService.class);
}
```

Comment: Quick question that may solve all of this: Do you use a task killer?  Is your app on its whitelist?

Comment: I'm actually using AutoKiller Memory Optimizer it doesn't have a whitelist this could be the issue? My app is running still though according the process list.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing obviously wrong.

For a long period like that, though, I'd recommend `RTC_WAKEUP`, so you can arrange for it to occur in the middle of the night or perhaps at a user-selectable time, rather than every 24 hours from a semi-random start point. It's possible `RTC_WAKEUP` will give you better results.

Also:

- Add a logging statement to `onReceive()` of `UpdateAlarmReceiver` to confirm whether you are getting control at all, or whether the problem is (gasp!) with `WakefulIntentService`.
- Try steadily increasing your period. Since you say 10 minutes works, try an hour, then four hours, etc., and try to get a sense when it breaks down.
- "I'm actually using AutoKiller Memory Optimizer it doesn't have a whitelist this could be the issue? My app is running still though according the process list." -- I would disable all task killers, just to be sure they are not interfering.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I have already added logging in various places, with the long interval its not even hitting the alarm receiver so im pretty sure its the alarm manager at fault somewhere. I have now disabled the memory optimizer, ill try all the other suggestions.

Comment: @Rob: The only things I know of that will get rid of a scheduled alarm are: if you `cancel()` it, if the user Force Stops it from Manage Services in the Settings app, or if a task killer stops it (and that might only be a problem on 2.1 and earlier -- I would not expect `killBackgroundProcesses()` to wipe out alarms, but I may be wrong there). Hopefully you will find that AutoKiller was the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting it not to repeat. Then when it fires off you set the next single shot alarm for 24 hours later? This would function like a repeating alarm but might avoid some of the problems you are seeing.

Comment: I have no considered this. I thought that was basically what setRepeating did. I will give it try though, thanks.

Comment: I made an alarm clock type application and this is how I handled it and it seemed to work out for me correctly prompting the AlarmActivity to start up at the correct time the next day. I've never used the setRepeating() flag though so I am not sure about why that wouldn't work, it seems to me too like these two approaches should function the same. Could it be that it isn't waking the device up properly when it triggers?

Comment: I think it's waking up fine, im using `WakefulIntentService` which uses `PowerManager.WakeLock`